# ONCLICK event without propagation?

Tags: html, css, layout, event-bubbling

I have a DIV nested inside another DIV. The parent DIV has a black background color with an opacity and the child DIV has a background color of white and is centered both vertically and horizontally.

I need both the parent and child DIV to disappear when the parent DIV with the opacity is clicked on. But for some reason when I click the child DIV (white DIV) the ONCLICK event gets triggered... i only need it to trigger when the parent DIV is clicked on...

It's because of bubbling??

And if so how do I prevent it and my main question is what is the best way to have this layout so I get both DIV to disappear when only the black opacity DIV is clicked on?

[image]

Comment: Show us the JS code that you're using. A screenshot doesn't quite illustrate things.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.target property to know on which element the click event is triggered. in the parent onclick listener you can check the event target and if it is not parent element then return from the listener.

Answer (score 0):

To pass on click event you can add `pointer-events: none;` CSS attribute to your child div